# Using two different third party libraries gives linking error

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, shared-libraries, linker-errors

I am using two different third party libraries in my VC++ project . When I compile them then its giving me linking errors.

I have checked the sample applications with each of the library.
Settings of sample application with first library (Lib1)

- 1)Use MFC in Static Library
- 2)Multi-Threaded Debug

Settings of sample application with first library (Lib2)

- 1)Use MFC in a shared dll
- 2)Multi-Threaded Dll

I am including first library in project by adding

```
#pragma comment(lib, "./lib/abc.lib")
```

statement

Second library is added to project settings by adding it as Additional Dependencies.

Now it works fine but when I try to use some functions from Lib1 the I get errors like

> 1>libcmtd.lib(tidtable.obj) : error
>   LNK2005: __encode_pointer already
>   defined in msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(tidtable.obj) : error
>   LNK2005: __decode_pointer already
>   defined in msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error
>   LNK2005: _malloc already defined in
>   msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
>   1>libcmtd.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error
>   LNK2005: _calloc already defined in
>   msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)

Any solution how can I make my project compile with both the libraries. I dont have source code for those libraries so I can't compile them.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to not use the debug build of library 1. Can you get/use the release build?
That way you are not linking against debug AND release version of system dll's.

If you cannot obtain the release build, then you will have to exclude the debug .libs from being used.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) explains how to do it.

The libs that end with d are the debug versions (libcmtd.lib). Those are the one you wish to exclude (for your release build). For you debug build you will want to exlcude the release libs.

Comment: I cannt get the release build.I have added NODEFAULTLIB but I get lots of errors. So looks like I need to explicitly specify all these libraries. I am getting around 700 errors . Is there a list of default libraries that I can include for a MFC project?

Comment: Instead of including the libs you need, exclude the libs which you do not want. In your example, for the release build, ignore libcmtd.lib.
What happens then?

Comment: I added two libraries libcmtd.lib msvcrtd.lib as "Ignore specific library" but still I am getting errors  like 1>Linking...
1>libcmtd.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __encode_pointer already defined in msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>libcmtd.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __decode_pointer already defined in msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)

Comment: If I am ignoring these two libraries then how can the above errors come.

Comment: You're still going to have issues because one library is built for the DLL version of the CRT, the other is built for the .lib version.  In general you don't want to mix and match, it's a recipe for disaster.